# How can I enable MSSQL support for PHP on a Linux server?

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to enable MSSQL support on my Linux server via PHP. I can't seem to figure out the proper way to go about this. Some threads suggested I install php5-sybase. I did this, but I'm not sure that this has all of MSSQL's functionality in it, not to mention that sybase is a different RDMBS all together, right?

What do I need to do to run MSSQL queries on a Linux box via PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: I'm not _actually_ sure what your question is. You want to connect to an MSSQL db and execute queries using PHP? Or you want to *host* an MSSQL instance on a linux box? If it's the latter, it's difficult - although folks have worked around it (FreeTDS)

Comment: From the php online maual: To use the MSSQL extension on Unix/Linux, you first need to build and install the FreeTDS library. Source code and installation instructions are available at the FreeTDS home page: http://www.freetds.org/

Comment: SRI, former, not the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to install freeTds as drivers for mssql server and after that you have to install php-mssql extension for php support following are some tutorials you can use:

1. http://guywyant.info/log/206/connecting-to-ms-sql-server-from-ubuntu/
2. https://secure.kitserve.org.uk/content/accessing-microsoft-sql-server-php-ubuntu-using-pdo-odbc-and-freetds
3. http://network-wizard.blogspot.ca/2009/03/install-freetds-on-ubuntu.html

You can use PDO following is the tutorial for that
http://ollieparsley.com/2014/05/29/linux-php-pdo-sql-server/